# ionic 2 popover position changes if app is open horizontal vs vertical

Tags: ios, css, angular, ionic2, popover

I'm working on a page that is always horizontal and there is a popup on that page.

If the app is launched horizontally, and the page is opened, the popup displays fine in the middle of the page as desired.

If the app is launched vertically, and the window is rotated as the page loads, the popup displays off center and low.

[image]

popover code:

```
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(ImageSigPopOverPage, {
  carriage: this.carriage,
  callback: data => {
    this.log.debug('message', 'In the callback for popover. The data returned: ', data);
    this.pad.fromDataURL(img);
    this._generateObject(data.title, img, data.subD);
  }
}, {showBackdrop: true, enableBackdropDismiss: true, cssClass: "pad--popover"});
popover.present();
```

Constructor:

```
_platform.ready().then(() => {
  screenOrientation.lock('landscape');
});
```

I cant seem to add any css that will affect the location unless it makes the popup window disappear completely, and then only inline.  (like `position: absolute; left:100px; top:100px;` poof.. cant find it any more)

How can I position this popover in the same space regardless of how the app opens?

Comment: Mediaqueries are useless here?

Comment: It may be my ignorance, but i've only been able to get inline css to affect the popover, and then only the style, not the positioning.  Cant seem to get any other css to work.

Comment: I am even more ignorant in Ionic ;)  I see you have cssClass: "pad--popover". Have you the stylesheet containing .pad--popover or it's like third party ?

Comment: I have scss for each page. (just like a standard angular2 project) but i'm not having luck testing to see if they are actually getting imported in my main .scss page.  I'm not that great in ionic yet either.

Comment: You can check in devtools to see with style is applied to which element.

Comment: I'm using VSCode to compile on IOS.  I'm not very good at xcode.. how would i find that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152200/discussion-between-vega-and-paqogomez).